# jasmine angular2 check array length toEqual return true

Tags: angular, jasmine

Hi I am new to angular2 and just finished the heroes example. I thought it would be good to add unit test and I started with hero.service.

this is hero service

getHeroes():Promise{

```
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl ).toPromise().then(response=>response.json().data as Hero[]).catch(this.handleError);
```

}

this is my unit test

```
const fakedHeroes:Hero[]=[
  { id: 1, name: 'Windstorm' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Tornado' }
]
 describe('get Heroes test',()=>{
    let service:HeroService=null;
    let backend:MockBackend=null;
    beforeEach(inject([HeroService,MockBackend],(heroSerivce:HeroService,mockBackend:MockBackend)=>{
        service=heroSerivce;
        backend=mockBackend;
    }));
    it('get heroes',(done)=>{

        backend.connections.subscribe((connection:MockConnection)=>{
            let options=new ResponseOptions({status: 200, body: {data: fakedHeroes}})
            connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
        })
        service.getHeroes().then(response=>{
            // console.log(response)
            console.log(response.length)
            expect(response.length).toEqual(2,'should be 4')

        });

        done();
    })
  })
```

from the console, I can see the length of the response is 4..but the test passes successfully..

Did I miss out anything here?

update1:

I have tried both

```
expect(response.length).toEqual(2,'should be 4')
expect(response.length).toBe(2,'should be 4')
```

all pass successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `done` is that is allows you to wait for async tasks to resolve. But you are not waiting for anything. You are calling it *synchronously*. You should be calling it after the async task resolves (in this case the promise), after you are "done" testing, i.e

```
service.getHeroes().then(res => {
  expect(...)

  done()
})
```